# Incorrect scaling with mouse after zoom

Tags: fabricjs

Thanks for reading this question :)

**Goal:**

I am using Fabric.js as a base for image editor (crop and resize features for now mostly).

My goal is to load some high-quality image (like photos) rotate or crop it and then export as DataURL (in original quality or near to it).

**Solution:**

To add such a big photo on canvas and be able to export it bad with the same quality - I set width and height of canvas equal to image's width and height (*2560 × 1600px*) and then compress it using css to *640x400px* (editor size). (I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/17035046 as a base)
In this case I still can export image in big dimension using canvas.toDataURL() - it will be about 2560x1600 (this is my goal).

How it works: http://jsfiddle.net/handmade/Lqsb0kwv/4/

**Problem description:**

I've got a problem after adding zoom feature (`canvas.zoomToPoint(...)`) to my editor and it is related to css width and height limitation of canvas.

Try to change size of image using controls in jsfiddle above and you will see an issue.

**Works fine if...**

...if I don't use css limitation: http://jsfiddle.net/handmade/Lqsb0kwv/5/

**Questions:**

I've read 90% of Fabric.js docs, examples, tutorials, questions here on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find a solution for my issue.

I am not sure that using css to limit canvas is a good practice.

I am not sure that my way of getting back changed image in big dimension is a good way.

Does anybody know better way to export image in good dimension?

Does anybody know if issue with scaling/rotating image after zoom (+limited by css) is a bug in Fabric.js?

*Thank you for any answer!*