# fabricjs toDataURL specify DPI

Tags: png, fabricjs, dpi

I'm trying to generate an image 1800px 2400px with 150DPI but I always get 72DPI.

```js
var image = canvas.toDataURL({
  left:150,
  top: 100,
  width: 180,
  height: 240,
  multiplier: 10
}).replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream")
```

How can I get a PNG with 150DPI ?

Comment: I'd try to use http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.html#DPI

Answer (score 1):

By default, your images are created in 72DPI. Since you send your image to server, you can convert the image to 150DPI using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) for example.

In PHP use this command:

```
$img150 = "convert input72image.png -units PixelsPerCentimeter -density 60x60 output150image.png;
exec ($img150);
```

PNG images are not converted in DPI but in "PixelsPerCentimeter". 
60 PixelsPerCentimeter are iqual to 152,4 DPI.

See these posts:
[What is the best practice to export canvas with high quality images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025603/what-is-the-best-practice-to-export-canvas-with-high-quality-images)
and 
[canvas.toDataURL() for large canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156402/canvas-todataurl-for-large-canvas)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have access to exec or any function of the like... can you add a php image magick object to demonstrate?