# Draw Image on Canvas and export print quality image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

**What I am Doing:**

I am using `Fabric.js` to develop a canvas application. Users can place image or texts in the canvas

**What I want to Do:**

When the user downloads the  image,the user should be able to print it. Currently I am working on length: `5 X 8` **(inches)**. In `Fabric.js`, `toDataURL()` function by default will give `72 DPI` image and I am planning on using `PHP` to convert it into `300dpi` image.

So  to create a high quality image of `5X8`  with `300dpi`, the image should be `1500px X 2400px`. But I cant give that much of space for the user since it wont be very intuitive.

So, I did what was suggested in the below link

[What is the best practice to export canvas with high quality images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025603/what-is-the-best-practice-to-export-canvas-with-high-quality-images)

**Problem:**

But I am facing a trouble. When the user places a text or image ,it appears very small.When I click on a text or image, the corners and borders are barely visible. It considers the relative size of the canvas. Please see the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3TMA/1042/)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not style canvas directly with dimensions.
Set the canvas attribute width and height, without exceeding the screen dimensions:

```
<canvas width="500" height="400" ></canvas>
```

When exporting to image use

```
canvas.toDataURL({multiplier: 4});
```

This will give you a canvas 4 times bigger the one on the screen.

Styling the canvas with the style to reduce its diemension and having a bigger image with dataURL will make the overall experience worse.

The style squeeze the canvas to your eyes with something that fabricjs is not ready to understand. So you will not get normal sized controls.

```
//remove those
width:400px !important;
height:600px !important;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3TMA/1043/

Comment: But that wont be so easy for the users to use..imagine a 1500px X 2400px lengths?

Comment: set the canvas with the right dimension with 1 on 1 pixel on screen, the output for printing with the size you prefer on your backend.

Comment: Cudn follow you...can u give some example?

Comment: Tried to improve answer.

Comment: I didn't know FabricJS has the useful `multiplier` property -- thanks for the info! :-)

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi: thanx for the suggestion..it partially worked, but while scaling, part of image is being cropped,any ideas?

Comment: it should not. post a fiddle, there is some error elsewhere.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi: Image is not getting downloaded with multipler property. It gives network error.Pls check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135417/download-canvas-as-png-in-fabric-js-giving-network-error