# How to increase the size of the downloaded image from canvas with fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using the following to download my fabricjs canvas and it works great but I wondered how I might be able to make the downloaded image larger so that it's clearer when I print it? Thanks for any help in advance.

```
// Download as png
function download(url, name) {
  // make the link. set the href and download. emulate dom click
  $('<a>').attr({
    href: url,
    download: name
  })[0].click();
}

function downloadFabric(canvas, name) {
  //  convert the canvas to a data url and download it.
  download(canvas.toDataURL(), name + '.png');
}
```

---

```
<button onclick="downloadFabric(canvas,'save');">Save</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw Image on Canvas and export print quality image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546206/draw-image-on-canvas-and-export-print-quality-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wound up being similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546206/draw-image-on-canvas-and-export-print-quality-image). From there I was able to work that adding `{multiplier: 4}` to `canvas.toDataURL();` worked splendidly.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the canvas width and height as bigger than the showing size.

```
<canvas width="2400" height="2400" style="width:600px;height:600px;"></canvas>
```

Because render `png` refers to canvas `width` and `height`.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qo2kt3am/)(you can get 2400x2400 image from the fiddle)